# Conditional template default values

Tags: c++, templates, conditional-statements

Let's say I have a function that returns a random number.

```
//defines the max value's interval
enum class Type {
    INCLUSIVE,
    EXCLUSIVE
};

template<typename T = int, Type Interval = Type::EXCLUSIVE>
T rand(const T min, const T max);
```

This currently works as expected, the usage is as follows:

```
int result = rand(1,6); //returns an int [1, 6)
double result = rand(1.0, 6.0); //returns a double [1.0, 6.0)
int result = rand<int, Type::INCLUSIVE>(1, 6); // returns an int [1, 6]
double result = rand<double, Type::INCLUSIVE>(1.0, 6.0); //returns a double [1.0, 6.0]
```

I want the `Interval` to have a default value depending on what `T` is passed in. For example, if `T` is an `int`, the `Interval` will be `EXCLUSIVE`. If `T` is a double (or floating point), `Interval` will be `INCLUSIVE`.

I tried using `std::conditional` like so:

```
template<typename T = int, typename Type Interval = std::conditional<std::is_integral<T>::value, Type::EXCLUSIVE, Type::INCLUSIVE>::type>
T RandomNumber(const T min, const T max);
```

Where the expected behavior is:

```
int result = rand(1,6); //returns an int [1, 6)
double result = rand(1.0, 6.0); //returns a double [1.0, 6.0]
//with the possibility of still overriding the default behavior e.g.
int result = rand<int, Type::INCLUSIVE>(1,6); //returns an int [1, 6]
```

I can't get it to work because I get `C2783` `could not deduce template argument for "Interval"`.

Is there another way of doing this or am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: `std::conditional` expect types, you're giving it values. In that case, you could simply replace it with a ternary `std::is_integral<T>::value ? Type::EXCLUSIVE : Type::INCLUSIVE`

Comment: In general, you could also have a traits class defining a `static constexpr Type value`.

Comment: @Caninonos - you should write your comments as an answer

Comment: @Caninonos Thanks, it was more simple than expected. If you write an answer I will accept it. Could you expand on the `Traits` class though?

Comment: A [traits](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/442) class is a template class whose purpose is to provide information about its template parameter by leveraging specialization. There are some examples in the standard library ([type_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits), [numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits), [iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits)... ). In that case, the default value could be e.g.`default_behaviour<T>::value` where `default_behaviour` is a traits class and `value` a static member.